# UISwipeGestureRecognizer for swipe down keyboard error

Tags: ios, swift

I have:

```
    var swipe: UISwipeGestureRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "dismissKeyboard")
    swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Down
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipe)
```

and

```
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

    func dismissKeyboard() {
        self.messageTextView.resignFirstResponder()
    }

}
```

When I swipe down on the device I get the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[AppName.ViewController dismissKeyboard]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x125d06500'
```

I have a lot of other code in my viewDidLoad plus my messageTextView is inside of a UIView which is in a UITableView. What could be the problem?

Comment: why your dismissKeyboard function are inside didReceiveMemoryWarning function ? I think that's the problem : Nested functions are hidden from the outside world by default

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dismissKeyboard` method is nested in your `didReceiveMemoryWarning` method. This is wrong. You have to declare your `dismissKeyboard` method as a method of your view controller. Then it should work.

By the way. You say that your `messageTextView` is embedded in a table view? The `UITableView` class already offers an opportunity to dismiss the keyboard on swipe. You simply have to set its `dismissMode` like this:

```
tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
```

Checkout the [Documentation for UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode).

Comment: Thanks guys. I was following a video tutorial so I guess I misplaced it. I'll confirm it when I get home. Thanks for the tip about the tableView.

Comment: @ali-ab Thanks. It works. I can't believe I did that lol. crox the `tableView.keyboardDismissMode` code, where do I put it and isn't it only effective in the scrolling part of the tableView?  Which leads me to my next question. I just noticed that my UIView dock (design element that holds the UITextView) , they are both actually outside of the UITableView. Should those two elements be nested inside the UITableView? Maybe that's why my sent messages that are saved on Parse aren't displaying/retrieved to my tableView? Parse back-end everything is showing up.

Comment: croX thank you too. I put your name in but it didn't post. Weird. Anyway, marked as correct.

Comment: Glad it helped. To your question: As I don't know your code and your Viewcontroller layout, I can't tell wether all of your UI-Elements should be nested inside of the tableview. It is usually a good idea to use fullscreen tableview, though. To your other question: You can put the `tableView.keyboardDismissMode` code into `viewDidLoad`. Give it a try.

Comment: ok so that brings up another question. Is it possible to have a drag/swipe down for the tableView? So at first it is fullscreen with all the messages and then if a user drags the top of the tableView down it can be shrunk/lowered towards the textView. Is this easy to do? Just create another gestureRecognizer function? Exact same code in the function? The call would be `func lowerTableView() {
        self.TableView.resignFirstResponder()
    }
`  Like that? But resign means dismiss. I just want to lower it by dragging it arbitrarily.

Comment: Hmm, I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Maybe  give it a try yourself, and if you remain stuck with a problem, ask another question with a detailed description and your code samples.

Comment: I did. Take a look at my new question please  I hacked together some stuff from another toot last night so when I confirm the code I will post some snippets of the code as well in that new question.

Comment: code added. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29191044/uievent-dragging-shorten-tableview-with-uitapgesturerecognizer